# creating a mock doesn't initialize a inline-initialized member

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, spy

I try to create a mock:

```
    final CofmanServiceNet cofmanService = mock(CofmanServiceNet.class);
```

of this class:

```
public class CofmanServiceNet implements CofmanService {
    private CofmanClient cofmanClient;
    private Logger logger = LoggingUtils.getLogger();
    private JsonUtility jsonUtility = new JsonUtility();

...

}
```

However I see the `logger` member is not initialized while  I call the real method:

```
    when(cofmanService.updatePartnerFromCurrentProto(anyObject(), anyObject())).thenCallRealMethod();
```

Comment: Why do you call the real method? That's not a good sign for your test design. You should do something like `thenReturn()` or `thenAnswer()`, otherwise you're leaving unit test territory.

Comment: I usually mock only when i go out of process (IO, net). When the logic is in-house I don't mock the method